# How to backup a list of URI

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-permissions, android-backup-service

My problem is a bit tricky to explain but I will do my best.

I have an object called "Store" that contains a list of URI paths (in String format) that have been previously selected by the user using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Because URI's are not serializable, I am storing those URI paths in string format inside my "Store" Object.

```
public void selectSong()
{
    Intent openFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    openFileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    openFileIntent.setType("audio/mpeg");
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
{
    if (getActivity() == null)
        return;

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case PICK_MP3_FILE:

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
            {                   
                
                Uri mp3AudioFile;
                if ((mp3AudioFile = data.getData()) != null)
                {
                    getActivity().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(mp3AudioFile, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    insertAudio(mp3AudioFile);
                    
                    Store store = new Store();
                    store.setSongPath(mp3AudioFile.toString());
                }                                       
            }
            break;

    }
}
```

When I need to convert that path into a URI, I simply call URI.parse() and it works great. I also have access to it after a reboot.

My requirement is to create a backup of this store object, so if the user deletes the app or updates the app, they can restore the Store object and still have access to the paths contained within that object. And this is where my problem lies. When I delete the app, and try load the backup file, the URI's permission grants within it are all revoked which are confirmed by running the following statement.

```
//This returns false
boolean permission = getContext().checkUriPermission(mp3SongPath, Binder.getCallingPid(),  Binder.getCallingUid(), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```

So here is my question, how can I grant permission to a URI in between app installs or even just re-grant the permission without having to display the filepicker to the user again? Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve I am trying to do? I read countless android documents, but I am still not out of the woods.

Thanks in advance
Joana

Comment: No. If you deinstall your app all your permissions are gone. You can save the uri strings somewhere but they are useless after reinstall as you have seen.

Comment: Further you do not need a Store as you can always ask the OS the uries for which you have permanent permissions. (Unless you put more information in the store instance then you showed us).

Comment: Updating an app is ok.

Comment: Thank you @blackapps.  Yes I do have some more information in Store but it is not relevant  to the URI. I was also thinking if I could store the URI id (if that is possible) and use the MediaStore to retrieve it when restoring the playlist after app reinstall.

Comment: Then you could as well store the whole uri string. But how would you obtain those media store uries to begin with?

Comment: On Android 10/11 you can use a function to convert a saf uri to a mediastore uri. You could save those media store uries instead. Or just add to your Store class. Maybe they are still valid after reinstall. Dont know. Please test it out. Then tell me. I like to know.

Comment: Problem is it needs to be backwards compatible not just Android10/11 :) . It is difficult, but I was thinking if I could just use the name of the audio (mp3) and use a cursor. The Uri's I could use Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

Comment: Yes, maybe that works. You could also try if the conversion function i talked about can change a saf uri to a media uri after reinstall of app. Maybe no permissions are needed for conversion.

Comment: I tried. You cannot. You get a SecurityException.

Comment: Thank you for the help @blackapps :) I will try the method I described, if it works I will post the solution here. Spent hours on this already